# Doxygen does not generate documentation for functions having arguments with defined data-type

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen

I am using Doxygen for generating documentation for python code. It does not generate documentation for functions having arguments with pre-defined data types. For example, it generates documentation for this function:

```
def func(a):
    #code
```

But not for this function:

```
def func(a:int):
    #code
```

Why does this happen and how can this be fixed ?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? I do see documentation of both functions though the argument in case of `a:int` is not handled properly in doxygen.

Comment: @albert well I've used `a:int` as an example. Actually I'm using a class as a data type like this `a:class_name`

Comment: Please provide a, small, complete example.